# Use Application.Wait immediately after a workbook opens

Tags: vba, excel

I need my workbook to display a certain color after I open it. Then after 5 seconds I would like the color to change. So I implemented to following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End Sub
```

However when I click on my file, it loads for 5 seconds and then opens and displays only the second color. How would I fix this while still using application.wait.

Comment: Increase you time...

Comment: Perhaps add a wait time before the first line too.  Maybe while Excel is still opening the file, the first line is being run. So the file actually takes let's say 3 seconds to open, but the first line fired immediately, so you have a brief moment to see it?

Comment: na, the file doesn't actually open until the workbook_open sub is done. So if I set wait to be say 30 seconds, then it will take 30 seconds of loading and I won't see anything until it's done those 30 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this and it worked.

Use this in the Workbook_Open

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Schedules a procedure to be run at a specified time in the future
    '(either at a specific time of day or after a specific amount of time has passed).
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "DoThis"
End Sub
```

Put this in a module. Not Thiswork or it won't work

```
Private Sub DoThis()
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End Sub
```

Comment: ya I figured I'd have to end up using OnTime. I was hoping for there to be a workbook event that occurs after the file has loaded and is being displayed. Nevertheless it solves my problem so checkmark for you.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the posed question, here's a workaround without using `OnTime` if you really, really had to...

It is possible to fire an event immediately after `Workbook_Open`. You could force a `Worksheet_Activate` event by manipulating the active sheet in the `Workbook_Open` sub. Then you could use your original `Application.Wait` code inside of `Worksheet_Activate`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Sheets(2).Activate
    Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End Sub
```